# Can't upgrade to 10.7.2 over a previous iCloud beta seed

Tags: macos, icloud, software-update

I never got the 10.7.2 update, as you can see here:

[image: installed software updates]

But my system thinks it's running 10.7.2:

[image: about this mac]

Running Software Update tells me there are no available updates, but 10.7.2 clearly isn't fully installed because I have no iCloud PrefPane:

[image: preference panes--no iCloud]

I've tried installing both the 10.7.2 client and client combo from [Apple's support downloads site](http://support.apple.com/downloads/), but when I try to run them, I get an error saying it can't be installed:

[image: installer error]

Is there a way to force Software Update to pull down the update? Or perhaps I could download the one it already installed? I don't think it's actually running 10.7.2, as I also don't have Safari 5.1.1:

[image: about safari]

Comment: Did you install any 10.7.2 beta or GM version before?

Comment: I installed beta versions before Lion was released, then installed Lion from the App Store. Now that I look at it, I also don't see the 10.7.1 update.

Comment: You need to do a clean install of Lion ( App Store ).

Comment: You have destroyed your system by not using the reversioners. There is no "fixing" this other than reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks for the reversioner tip, @cksum. System not destroyed.

Comment: You are certainly braver than me. Applying two core updates without reversioners and then going back to a previous version? I'm surprised your system's even remotely stable! The reversioners can let you reinstall the combo update but that's no guarantee it'll fix any problems deep within the system. I'd reinstall Lion if I were you. No telling what kind of systemic problems you might face as a result!

Comment: @cksum, I didn't apply any core updates--System Update wouldn't install them because I hadn't run the reversioner. And I didn't go back to a previous version. In the end, I think I did exactly what someone with access to all the betas would have done--installed previous betas, ran the reversioner, then ran a normal system updater.

Comment: You can't do that. Running betas means running the same version number (eg 10.7.1) but a different build. That's what a reversioner is for. To "trick" OS X into thinking its running a different VERSION. So if you installed a slew of betas without the reversioners, you've likely introduced a ton of inconsistencies within the core files. Rerunning the combo won't fix those because that's now how system installs work. Hey it could be fine, but chances are, it won't be.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I've done. I ran iCloud betas, which are 10.7.2 betas. There were no reversioners with those betas--the reversioner was introduced after I lost access to beta seeds. Then I ran reversioner that comes with a later version of the iCloud beta. It's exactly what anyone would have done if they installed early, but not later, betas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by running the revisioner, thanks in part to @cksum's comment. After running the revisioner, I ran Software Update and it installed the 10.7.2 update.

Here's what happened:

I'm an iOS developer. Apple gave WWDC attendees access to the early Lion betas, even if they weren't in the Mac developer program. After beta 6, [Apple stopped giving us access to the Lion seeds](https://devforums.apple.com/message/508577#508577). So I never had a Lion beta that included a reversioner. The reversioner basically resets the state of the system so the 10.7.2 upgrade package thinks you're running 10.7.1, so it can install over previous seeds.

I was able to get a copy of the reversioner from a friend in the Mac developer program, and now I'm good to go.

Answer (score 1):

While i haven't seen this problem with Lion, it was common with previous versions of OS X. The way to fix it was to download the Combo updater from Apple, and run the update. Apple provides this for Lion at http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1459, so i'd download that first, run it, and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: This does not apply to any version that has installed a private build. The OP did not apply them properly, hence the problem. This is a unique case that a member of the public would never suffer from. Perhaps a good illustration of why it's crucial to read the manual ;)

Comment: Silly me, i need to RTFM!